# count occurrence of particular text in txt file

Tags: vb.net, text, count, text-files

Dose anybody know how I can tally instances of a particular text occurrence within a txt file using VB.net. Better explanation if I use a textbox and type in a text how I can use VB.net to search a txt file for that piece of text and return the amount counted in another textbox or label.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also use LINQ to achieve this:

```
Dim separator = {" "c}
Dim words = (From line As String In IO.File.ReadLines("C:\Temp\SampleFile.txt")
            From word In line.Split(separator, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            Where word = TxtWordToFind.Text).Count
```

The same in method syntax(crabbed in VB):

```
words = IO.File.ReadLines("C:\Temp\SampleFile.txt").
        SelectMany(Function(line) line.Split(separator, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)).
        Where(Function(word) word = TxtWordToFind.Text).Count
```

Comment: Tim it looks like this just counts words, not specific occurences of words?

Comment: @BartvanTuÿl: I assume that you've missed the `Where word = TxtWordToFind.Text` in my code. Basically i'm reading all lines in the file, split these into words(sepatared by `" "`), selecting only the words that are equal with the word entered in the TextBox(note that it's case-sensitive) and finally count the matches.

Comment: My appologies I have my stuipid hat on today Tim but I'm getting that Words, SelectMany and Where are having declaration errors..?

Comment: vb.net I had added the dim as string for all the above however it ended in another error again

Comment: @BartvanTuÿl: I've [Option Infer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384665.aspx)`On` by default. However, this is also new in VisualStudio 2008. So i'm asking again, are you using Visual Studio 2005(.NET framwork 2.0)?